# How to validate a field's input value using regular expression in autoform in meteor on client side?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, meteor, meteor-autoform

i'm new to meteor framework and i'm building a form which needs validation of fields using regular expression in client side.

**schema.js**

```
   PRODUCT_BUILD:{
    type:String,
    label:' PRODUCT_BUILD', 
    defaultValue:"PRODUCT:latest",
    regEx: /^(PRODUCT)((\/(([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+))|(\:(latest)))/
  },
```

I have written the message as

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
 'regEx PRODUCT_BUILD': "Can have eg: PRODUCT/10.X.X.1234 or PRODUCT:latest",
});
```

**test.html**

```
 {{> afQuickField name='PRODUCT_BUILD'}}
```

I have entered all the fields which regex needs, but when I give the invalid input it dosen't check the regex and also the error message.
Can anyone tell me what i can do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

As for as I remember, the way simple schema messages are handled have been changed in the recent versions of simple-schema / autoform.

Ideally, it used to be something like this (which I'm not sure if it's going to work on your version):

```
SimpleSchema.messages({
  "regEx PRODUCT_BUILD": [
    { msg: "Can have eg: PRODUCT/10.X.X.1234 or PRODUCT:latest" }
  ]
});
```

There is an alternate method using custom field validation as below:

```
  PRODUCT_BUILD:{
    type:String,
    label:' PRODUCT_BUILD', 
    defaultValue:"PRODUCT:latest",
    custom: function(){
            if(this.value){
               // do the regex validation using normal JS
              //if validation fails,
               return "regexError"
             }
           }
  },


SimpleSchema.messages({
  "regexError":  "Can have eg: PRODUCT/10.X.X.1234 or PRODUCT:latest" 

});
```